# Create post filter in custom wp-query

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a filter bar for my post feed on WordPress.

I'm trying to achieve this using the `$_GET` method where I change Wp-query based on the parameters present in the URL.

For some reason it's not working for all the cases; note that the parameters are

1. Year
2. Month
3. Category
4. Keywords

And this is my wp-query code:

```
$current_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];


    $count = 0; $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;


    if ( !isset($_GET['year']) && !isset($_GET['monthnum']) && !isset($_GET['category']) && !isset($_GET['string'])){

        $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'category_name' => 'Press Release', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>4, 'paged' => $paged ));
    }

    if( isset($_GET['year']) || isset($_GET['monthnum']) || isset($_GET['category']) || isset($_GET['string']) ){

        if( isset($_GET['year']) ){

            $year = $_GET['year'];

            $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post',   'year' => $year,'category_name' => "Press Release", 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>4, 'paged' => $paged ));

        }

        if( isset($_GET['monthnum']) ){

            $monthnum = $_GET['monthnum'];

            $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post',   'monthnum' => $monthnum,'category_name' => "Press Release", 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>4, 'paged' => $paged ));
        }

        if( isset($_GET['category']) ){

            $category = $_GET['category'];

            $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'category_name' =>  "$category", 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>4, 'paged' => $paged ));
        }

        if( isset($_GET['string']) ){

            $string = $_GET['string'];

            $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', '_name__like' => $string, 'category_name' => "Press Release", 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>4, 'paged' => $paged ));

        }

        if( isset($_GET['year']) && isset($_GET['monthnum']) ){

            $year = $_GET['year'];
            $monthnum = $_GET['monthnum'];

            $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post',  'monthnum' => $monthnum, 'year' => $year,'category_name' => "Press Release", 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>4, 'paged' => $paged ));

        }


        if( isset($_GET['year']) && isset($_GET['monthnum']) ){

            $year = $_GET['year'];
            $category = $_GET['category'];

            $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post',  'year' => $year,'category_name' => "$category", 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>4, 'paged' => $paged ));

        }

        if( isset($_GET['year']) && isset($_GET['string']) ){

            $year = $_GET['year'];
            $string = $_GET['string'];

            $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post',  'year' => $year, '_name__like' => $string, 'category_name' => "Press Release", 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>4, 'paged' => $paged ));

        }

        if( isset($_GET['monthnum']) && isset($_GET['category']) ){

            $monthnum = $_GET['monthnum'];
            $category = $_GET['category'];

            $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post',  'monthnum' => $monthnum, 'category_name' => "$category", 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>4, 'paged' => $paged ));

        }

        if( isset($_GET['monthnum']) && isset($_GET['string']) ){

            $monthnum = $_GET['monthnum'];
            $string = $_GET['string'];

            $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post',  'monthnum' => $monthnum, '_name__like' => $string, 'category_name' => "Press Release", 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>4, 'paged' => $paged ));

        }

        if( isset($_GET['category']) && isset($_GET['string']) ){

            $string = $_GET['string'];
            $category = $_GET['category'];

            $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post',  '_name__like' => $string, 'category_name' => "$category", 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>4, 'paged' => $paged ));

        }

    }
```

Comment: _“For some reason it's not working for all the cases”_ - so for which isn’t it working, and what exactly does “not working” mean?

Comment: The structure with so many ifs is not really ideal. You should rather create an array for the parameters, and set the default values in there. Then, if `$_GET['year']` is set, you overwrite the according value in the array, and same for all the other criteria. And in the end, you feed that array to `new WP_Query(…)`. That way, you don’t have to handle all the possible combinations separately.

Comment: Alright, the string one isn't working "Keywords filter". And what I mean is that in case I play around with the URL using the $_GET parameters I mentioned above; the results aren't filtered, I still get everything.

Comment: By keywords, you mean the parameter that is actually named `string`? I can’t find `_name__like` documented anywhere here, https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query, so where did you get that from?

Comment: I tried this before, I created a less expended version but it didnt work I couldnt find a value to give the parameters so that they stop affecting the search in case they are not set yet. Lets say something like 'if( !isset($year)){$year = any}' so that it takes all the years.

Comment: Any idea what I should replace it with? I want to see if the written word is related to any of the post titles.

Comment: Well then only add them to the parameter array if the GET parameter is set in the first place …

Comment: If you are okay with search not only in the title, but the post content as well, then you can use https://codex.wordpress.org/wp_query#Search_Parameter

Comment: Will that do the trick? `  $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'category_name' => "Press Release", 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>4, 'paged' => $paged ));

  if(isset($_GET['category'])) {
   $wpb_all_query['category_name'] = "$category";
  }

  if(isset($_GET['string'])) {
   $wpb_all_query['_name__like'] = "$string";
  }

  if(isset($_GET['monthnum'])) {
   $wpb_all_query['monthnum'] = "$monthnum";
  }

  if(isset($_GET['year'])) {
   $wpb_all_query['year'] = "$year";
  }`

Comment: Ohh thanks! so I just need to replace _name__like with 's'?